# Can Windows 2008 send proper TCP termination once a process has been killed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, tcp

Meet "S" and "P" two server side apps connected via some TCP socket, both running on Windows 2008.
In fact, S connects to P using port 20202
At some point over the week end, P is killed without notice, which S finds with a connection reset.
S enters a connection retry loop for about 20seconds, then can connect back to port 20202 for about 1 second, then the connection gets dropped with proper TCP termination.
Hence my question : **Is Windows 2008 capable of sending TCP termination after P has been killed?** Or I am looking for a zombie?

Comment: By "TCP termination" do you mean resetting the TCP connection? Or do you mean an orderly shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

It's not Window sending the packet but the application. And yes, of course it can send the packet. I'd only be concerned if it got a reply from P, which is not running.